# Filepond http uploading files IIS server setup problem 405

Tags: file-upload, iis-10, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to get a uploading script running, filepond, uploading files through webpage. On IIS10, on co-located server.

When uploading, using POST, I get the following error:
HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

in details:

```
Module    DirectoryListingModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code    0x80070001
Requested URL    https://www.example.com:443/upl/files/
Physical Path    W:\www.example.com\www\upl\files\
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User    Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory    C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles
```

port 443 is open.

The folder has the following web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Write, Execute, Script">
                <remove name="StaticFile" />
                <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Write" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The folder has the following attributes:
IIS > site > folder > configuration Editor > system.webServer/handlers

FROM SITE/upl/files Web.config  > accesPolicy: Read, Write, Execute, Script

FROM SITE/upl  Web.config   > accesPolicy: Read, Execute, Script (no solution when adding "Write")

FROM ApplicationHost.config  accesPolicy: "Read, Execute, Script"

---

Athentication:  Anonymous Athentication status enabled, rest disabled

---

Handler Mappings > Static File

Path: *, State: enabled,

PathType: File or Folder,

Handler: StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule,

Entry Type: Local

EDIT > Request Restrictions > Mapping : selected Invoke handler only if request is mapped to File or folder, Verbs: GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,

Access: Write ( I dont understant why there is no Read/Write option, only read / write / script / execute )

---

Properties > security >
even when giving full control on that folder to Everyone + IUSR + IIS_IUSRS + Users : still same error.

---

I did notice in Handler Mappings there is no *.js record.
In Handler Mappings changing the *.asp > edit > "file" to "file and folder" had no effect either.

Jic: I could not find Filepond using a temp folder that I forgot to give acces rights to.

Jic; these are my present FilePond server settings:

```
    FilePond.setOptions({
        server: {
            url: 'https://www.example.com/upl/',
            timeout: 3000,
            process: {
                url: 'files/',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'x-customheader': 'Hello World',
                },
                withCredentials: false,
                onload: (response) => response.key,
                onerror: (response) => response.data,
                ondata: (formData) => {
                    formData.append('Hello', 'World');
                    return formData;
                },
            },
            revert: './revert',
            restore: './restore/',
            load: './load/',
            fetch: './fetch/',
        }
    });
```

I looked at all the previous answers here and elsewhere for over a day now, but seem to miss a tiny vital thing. Any help is very much appreciated !!

Alex

------------ replying to Samwu:

Thank you for helping.
The above represents most of the solutions I looked at.
I followed the link, found this earlier and here are some findings:

- the client makes a Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) request by using an HTTP method that doesn't comply with the HTTP specifications.
  In the ApplicationHost.config file, Make sure that all the handlers use valid HTTP methods.
  from my applicationHost.config:

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
  <add name="ASPClassic" path="*.asp" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="File" />
  <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="GET,POST" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Write" />
</handlers>
<sectionGroup name="webdav">
    <section name="globalSettings" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
    <section name="authoring" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
    <section name="authoringRules" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
</sectionGroup>
```

all the modules are stated in applicationHost.config modules

I did notice however something: in the www root there is a web.config that says:

```
        <remove name="ASPClassic" />
        <remove name="StaticFile" />
        <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
        <add name="ASPClassic" path="*.asp" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
```

in the upl / files / dir there is a webconfig saying:

```
    <system.webServer>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Write, Execute, Script">
        <remove name="StaticFile" />
        <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Write" />
    </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

notice the " requireAccess="Script" instead of Write

"Send the POST request to a page that's configured to be handled by a handler other than the StaticFile handler. For example, the ASPClassic handler. "

I assume that if my filepond js module is included in a .asp page that this is what I am all ready doing.

WebDav is not installed, it is still stated in the applicationHost.config. Removing that gives an error on restarting the site in IIS.

I hope that clearifies.

Comment: What solutions have you tried? may be this link can help you: [HTTP Error 405.0 when you visit a website that is hosted on a server that is running IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-405-website).

Comment: Thanks for helping, my reply is in the original question.

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.